# Create function event scroll swipe Typescript

Tags: angularjs, typescript, scroll, swipe

I have the following piece of code that manages when scrolling with the keys up and down the keyboard:

```
KeyEvents() {

    if (this.subskey != undefined)
      this.subskey.unsubscribe();

    this.subskey = this.APPService.keyEvent$.subscribe((event) => {

      switch (event.keyCode) {

        case this.keyCodes.KEY_UP:
          this.isText('UP');
          break;
        case this.keyCodes.KEY_DOWN:
          this.isText('DOWN');
          break;
      }
    });
  }
```

Then with the isText(direction) function  and a switch I can do the actions I want as I move down or up. For example when I move down I put an arrow. What I want to do is do the same but for a swipe event, that is, if I swipe down or up, I do different actions. I hope someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into [Hammer.js](http://hammerjs.github.io/getting-started/). Hammer has support for almost all the touch-based events. It also has an [angularjs](http://ryanmullins.github.io/angular-hammer/) based directive..

If you are planning to use Angular with typescript, angular itself supports [Hammer configuration](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG). Here is an [example on Fun with Hybrid Mobile Apps](http://funwithhybrid.blogspot.com/2017/03/ionic2-hammer-js-example.html) based on same, although it is developing mobile application using Ionic, the angular part will remain same.